# How to balance tree with single branch?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-balancing

If we had, say, nodes of value 10, 9 ... 1 arranged in descending order on a single left branch, how could we perform rotations on the tree to make it a balanced AVL tree? I was thinking of repeating single right rotations, but could someone show the sequence of steps here?

Comment: You can reverse the single left branch tree to create a single right branch tree (called a vine), then convert vine to tree. Link to [rebalance tree.pdf](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~qstout/pap/CACM86.pdf) .

Answer (score 2):

Do rotations at the root until 5 is at the top. The tree is now an upside down V. Now do a similar operation on each of the two subtrees and so on.